# Виртуальная машина и впн

Tags: vpn, python-openai

Я создал бот телеграм для автокомиентинга. Генерирует комментарии он с помощью чатпгт библиотеки `openai`. А она не работает без впн.

Вопрос такой, как на виртуальную машину Ubuntu 22.04 (vk cloud если это важно) установить впн или любым другим способом заставить работать?

Я устанавливал туда `openvpn` и подключался к серверу, все работало но после этого я не мог подключиться к машине, только после перезагрузки. 
Я пока не очень силен в впн и виртуальных машинах, надеюсь на вашу помощь, спасибо заранее.

Comment: после запуска vpn адрес вашей машины в интернете видимо меняется и уже надо подключаться через другой (vpn) адрес